# Debuging Devise in simple Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I configure Devise gem for Rails and in code it seems look OK but when I'm trying to register new user I have the problem.
In register form Devise show notice:

> Please review the problems below:

but that's all. Nothing specific message. Where I should looking for first? How to debug something like this?
Any suggestions?

Log from rails server:

> Started POST "/auth/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-14 17:09:13
>   +0200 Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"iRsLU68tBckSzK1tupMoXZQlGw7xOuzMlfuiIVVs+rc=",
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
>   (0.2ms)  BEGIN   User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" 
>   WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
>   Rendered devise/shared/_links.haml (0.5ms)   Rendered
>   devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (15.9ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 121ms (Views: 24.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

And when I try log in:

> Started POST "/auth/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-14 17:10:23 +0200
>   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"iRsLU68tBckSzK1tupMoXZQlGw7xOuzMlfuiIVVs+rc=",
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT 
>   "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@test.com'  ORDER
>   BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
>   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"iRsLU68tBckSzK1tupMoXZQlGw7xOuzMlfuiIVVs+rc=",
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}   Rendered
>   devise/shared/_links.haml (0.4ms)   Rendered
>   devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (9.8ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 15.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: What do the Rails log show?

Comment: can you post registerations controller and logs when you submit sign up form?

Comment: I added log but I don't know how should I read it. Can you give me some advices about reading this log from server console?

Comment: @Jensky do you have any custom validations? Do you have flash messages to show validation errors?

Comment: Hmm, this is default, I've not changed it. I checked users database and it's empty (0 rows). What do you think, where I should looking for problem?

Comment: @Jensky you log says `..ROLLBACK..` so there is something in your app which is causing it to rollback. Do you have flash messages conatiner in your app to show devise error?

Comment: No, I get only standard errors like 'password too short' or 'can't be blank'. When form is OK I don't get any information about problem so I don't know where I should looking for.

Comment: Try to create a user in console.  `rails c` u = User.new("email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"<enter something here>", "password_confirmation"=>"<enter something here>").  Then you can see if it saves or errors.  You can inspect `u.errors` here.

Answer (score 1):

I debug these things by inspecting the object.errors

In this case, try to

```
raise @user.errors.inspect
```

Somewhere after the save in the create method

Comment: Can you show me a context or a little more verbose code? I'm beginner and I've never used method like this.